# Handlebars conditional checked property from Jade template

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js, pug

I'd like my handlebars template that's served to the client to look like

```
<input type='checkbox' checked={{isChecked}}>
```

or

```
<input type='checkbox' {{#if isChecked}}checked{{/if}}>
```

How can I write a Jade template that will compile to this? from their docs, the checked property will be included if the assigned value is truthy but not actually include the value:

```
input(type="checkbox", checked="{{isChecked}}")
```

compiles to

```
<input type='checkbox' checked>
```

I've also tried:

```
input(type="checkbox", checked={{isChecked}})
```

and

```
input(type="checkbox", {{#if isChecked}}checked{{/if}})
```

that just fails to compile, which I understand

Answer (score 21, accepted):

well try it directly in your jade template.

```
<input type='checkbox' {{#if isChecked}}checked{{/if}}>
```

should stay in the same format.

[image: capture]

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest creating a more general helper that you can later reuse easily

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("checkedIf", function (condition) {
    return (condition) ? "checked" : "";
});
```

Then, you can use it in any of your templates:

```
<script id="some-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
   ...
   <input type="checkbox" {{checkedIf this.someField}} />
   ...
</script>
```

This will be rendered as

```
<input type="checkbox" checked />

 or...

<input type="checkbox" />
```

depending on the value of `someField` (a field of the object being mapped to the template)

Comment: How do you check for a negative one, like checked if false?

Comment: @dvidsilva I haven't used Handlebars in a long time now... does this work? `{{checkedIf !this.someField}}`?

Comment: not really, I ended up having to write checkedIf and checkedIfNot :O